# Why the curve is rational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry

I'm reading Beauville's book "Complex Algebraic Surfaces" and I have a question about Step 3 of the proof of Proposition VI.2:

Suppose we have a minimal surface $S$ with $K_S^2<0$ and Albanese map  $p:S\to B$ with connected fibers to a smooth curve $B$. Suppose that we also have an irreducible curve $C$ on $S$ such that $C\cdot K_S<-1$ and $|C+K_S|=\emptyset$. Moreover, $C$ is the section of $p$. Then by Riemann-Roch we conclude that $h^0(C)\ge 2$.

Then Beauville says that:
$C$ moves in its linear equivalence class. Let $F$ be a generic fiber of $p$; then the point $C\cap F$ moves linearly on $F$ and so $F$ must be rational.

I do not understand what does he mean by "$C\cap F$ moves linearly on $F$" and how does it give us that "$F$ must be rational"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: He's saying that by varying $C$ in a pencil, you get a single point on $F$ whose "motion" is parametrized by $\mathbb P^1$, so this gives you a 1-1 map $F \to \mathbb P^1$ hence an isomorphism.

Comment: How can I see that the motion is parametrized by $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that we have $C, C_1 \in| |C|$ and we can consider a pencil $\lambda C+\mu C_1$ and $\lambda$ will give this motion on $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you vary $C$ in a pencil, it cuts out a pencil of degree $1$ divisors on $F$, and this pencil induces a degree $1$ map $F \to \mathbb P^1$. Such maps are necessarily isomorphisms.